# IIS Manager only shows 2 icons (IIS 8 Server 2012 R2)

Tags: configuration, iis-8

I followed the instructions from the first answer on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493236/how-do-you-migrate-an-iis-7-site-to-another-server).

After restarting IIS Manager this is what is displayed:
[image]

This is what was expected (from the original server)
[image]

Steps taken:
1. Export the configuration from IIS Manager on the original Server.
2. Copy all files to the new server.
3. Add the IIS Role on the new Server.
4. Start the IIS manager on the new server.
5. Click the Shared Configuration icon on the new server.
6. Imported the configuration files from the original server.
7. Clicked Apply.
8. Closed IIS Manager
9. Restarted IIS Manager

Any ideas on how to get all the missing icons back?

Comment: The steps you took show a completely wrong way to migrate settings from one machine to another. Typical approaches should be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis To restore your server, disable Shared Configuration. If that does not help, reinstall IIS.

Comment: IIS was uninstalled. The root of the problem may have been that the .net settings hadn't been set first. IIS has been reinstalled but Default Web Site still isn't available.

Comment: `Default Web Site` is not mandate. You can create your own to replace it.