# How to Import iis configuration from export-iisconfiguration

Tags: .net, powershell, iis

I am trying to replicate a deployment that was done by hand on one windows server for IIS to another. For comparison from time to time I use `Export-IISConfiguration` cmdlet to assert if my configuration script is going in the right direction. After splitting my hairs (since for what ever reason static file handler gets executed, but not the handler configured in the application) I've decided to try importing the configuration that was produced by the old server via former command, but to my surprise, there is no `Import-*` counterpart for that command.

How *do* you import IISConfiguration?

Both nodes are on IIS10 running .net framework 4.8

Comment: Anytime you want to move a site from one server to another, you should use Web Deployment Tool, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis That's why there isn't a simple PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: The two machines are not in the same network nor can they install anything that's not available via dism or `add-windowsfeature` cmdlet.

Comment: Without using a convenient tool like that, a lot of manual steps are required and like I said no cmdlet is there to help.

Comment: That's fine. As long as I can call the appcmd directly and use that it's fine. That's why I am writing a script to begin with.

Comment: Powershell has list all cmdlet to import specific configuration of IIS. I'm not sure whick kind of configuration you want to migrate. But appcmd can backup the old IIS, then you can use appcmd import backup to new IIS.

Comment: I see a similar question like this which already has the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493236/how-do-you-migrate-an-iis-7-site-to-another-server

Comment: @LexLi - Does web deploy have any impact on the source website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enable-IISSharedConfig

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/enable-iissharedconfig?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35539994)