# How to import IIS settings that were exported from the `Shared Configuration` section?

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have exported the IIS settings from the `Shared Configuration` section.

1. I believe that the exported file contains all the IIS settings, app pool/settings, website/settings which can be restored onto another IIS server to replicate the configuration (for example - in case the 1st server crashes permanently).

How to import them onto another IIS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we Export the configuration and if you have stored it on the network drive(shared location) it will create 3 files like below.

[image]

You could check **Enable Shared Configuration** option and pass the shared location path and credentials.

[image]

It will give you some pop-ups, you could read them and take action.

After that, the configuration will be taken from those files.

Reference: [Shared Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/configuring-servers-in-the-windows-web-platform/shared-configuration_211)

Comment: My goal is to copy all the settings from one IIS to another IIS. Is there way to achieve that?

Comment: You could use the Shared Configuration as we discussed. Another option you could try is  [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy). You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500022/10309381) to get more detailed information.