# How to migrate IIS 7 settings to another server with IIS 10

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, migrate, windows-server-2019

i'm new with windows server and IIS stuff, and i got a question
the company i work for are trying to move old server with `[windows server 2008 & IIS 7 & SQL server 2008~2019 & visual SVN server]` to new server just bought`[windows server 2019]`
what we need on old IIS is the whole bunch of URL rewrite rules.
How can i migrate old settigs and data properly?

I've tried the backup command
`appcmd add backup [name]` and copy backup files to new server. On new server i've try `appcmd restore backup [name]`.
But the new server runs an error and IIS won't start up.
*Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID FROM the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800700b7*

The solution on MS community i found like re-install IIS and iisreset won't work.
the other solution tells me to delete 2 file under `\inetsrv\config\schema`
*NetFx40_IIS_schema_update.xm* & *NetFx45_IIS_schema_update.xml*
makes IIS start but in a strange way. It did transfer the rewrite rules, but that's the only thing left i can see on IIS management tools, all the other sites and apppools settings are gone and can't add a new one or restart sites.
it loooks like this
[failed backup restore result photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gztu.png)

Comment: Microsoft only documented a way to migrate site by site using Web Deploy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis#part-3--synchronize-your-site-to-the-target The backup approach you tried or "The solution on MS community i found" are totally irrelevant.

Comment: There was a similar discussion here that may provide some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493236/how-do-you-migrate-an-iis-7-site-to-another-server

Comment: Thanks!!! i'll do some research and take a try

Answer (score 0):

There are two web applications under the default website of the source server IIS, the following steps can realize the migration:

**Step 1: Install WEBDEPLOY on both source and target servers.**

Download link: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

**Step 2: Create the package in the source server.**

Open a command prompt and run the following command to backup the IIS configuration before proceeding with the migration:

```
C:\>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add backup "PreWebDeployMigration"
```

IIS configuration backup will be available in  `C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\backup` folder.

Change the path to web deploy installed directory in command prompt. The default path is `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3` folder. Then execute the following command to get the dependencies of the website. Verify the output of dependencies and ensure that these components are properly installed on the target server:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy -verb:getDependencies -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1
```

Execute the following command to create a compressed package file of the IIS website:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -dest:package=c:\Site1.zip > WebDeployPackage.log
```

All web applications under the default website are compressed into a zip file and placed under the `C:\ drive`. Move the compressed package to the destination server.

**Step 3: Extract the package in the target server.**

Execute the following command to verify packages with server dependencies

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site1.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -whatif > WebDeploySync.log
```

If any dependencies are missing in the target server, the above command will display the information

Once you verified the output, run the same command without –whatif option:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3> msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site1.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 > WebDeploySync.log
```

Finally open the target server IIS Manager and verify that the web application is available under Default Web Site.

Comment: i've followed the instruction of MSdeploy, but seems nothing happened.
the WebDeploySync.log under "~\web deploy V3" looks normal, just say files are added and update
but the rewrite rules never appears on the new server, what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

found a way that "might" work, haven't test yet so not quite sure 
after trying to migrate IIS to new server with msdeploy tool, the rewrite map is still empty
so i manually copy the  segment under applicationHost.config in system32\inetsrv to new server
will it work? or i'm still an idiot wasting time?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).